# How to Remove Empty Lines in an HTML output file using Regex in Java

Tags: java, html, regex, replace, format

The input in HTML is;

```
  <div>TODO write content</div>

  <span class="test"></span>
  <ruby>text1<rp>(</rp><rt>textA</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
  <ruby>
  text1<rp>(</rp><rt>textA</rt><rp>)</rp>
  text2<rp>(</rp><rt>textB</rt><rp>)</rp>
  text3<rp>(</rp><rt>textC</rt><rp>)</rp>
  </ruby>
  <img src="images/aaaaa.jpg"> 
  <img src="./audio/bbbbb.mp3">
```

This is needed to be modified in this format,

```
  <div>TODO write content</div>

  <span class="test"></span>
  <font class="ruby" title="textA">text1</font>
  <font class="ruby" title="textA">text1</font>
  <font class="ruby" title="textB">text2</font>
  <font class="ruby" title="textC">text3</font>
  <img src="images/aaaaa.jpg"> 
  <img src="./audio/bbbbb.mp3">
```

So, I applied these codes using REGEX and while loop;

```
final String REPLACE = "";

    final String REGEX_RUBY_1 = "<ruby>";
    final String REGEX__RUBY_2 = "</ruby>";
    Pattern rubyP_1 = Pattern.compile(REGEX_RUBY_1);
    Matcher rubyM_1 = rubyP_1.matcher(text);
    text = rubyM_1.replaceAll(REPLACE);

    Pattern rubyP_2 = Pattern.compile(REGEX__RUBY_2);
    Matcher rubyM_2 = rubyP_2.matcher(text);
    text = rubyM_2.replaceAll(REPLACE);

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<rt>(.+?)</rt>",Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\b(\\w*\\S)\\b)<rp>)",Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    final Matcher matcher2=pattern2.matcher(text);

    while(matcher.find()){
          matcher2.find();
          text="<font class=\"ruby\" title=\""+matcher.group(1)+"\""+">"+matcher2.group(1)+"</font>";
          break;
    }
```

But the output was,

```
  <div>TODO write content</div>

  <span class="test"></span>

<font class="ruby" title="textA">text1</font>
<font class="ruby" title="textA">text1</font>
<font class="ruby" title="textB">text2</font>
<font class="ruby" title="textC">text3</font>

  <img src="images/aaaaa.jpg"> 
  <img src="./audio/bbbbb.mp3">
```

the replacing was fine, but the format was different since there are empty lines and the replaced texts were aligned left. I tried to modify some codes and searched for some possible codes to be applied it seems that it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

For indent the file change the first pattern to this:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^( +).+<rt>(.+?)</rt>",Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

and then change the text assignement like this:

```
text=matcher.group(1)+"<font class=\"ruby\" title=\""+matcher.group(2)+"\""+">"+matcher2.group(1)+"</font>";
```

and for get rid of White lines try this:

```
final String REGEX_RUBY_1 = "<ruby> *\n?";
final String REGEX__RUBY_2 = "</ruby> *\n?";
```

Comment: It returns, "No Match Found".